# How to sync AWS S3 buckets between accounts without AWS CLI or a script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to know if there is a way to sync AWS S3 buckets using a out of the box tool instead of AWS CLI commands like `aws s3 sync` or a server or lambad to run a script for the same.

Basically I would like to know if there is an AWS tool that does this exactly and keep the two buckets synced regularly or if there a third party application which would do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, S3 has a [built-in replication feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html), which supports replicating across accounts.

Comment: This will only replicate objects created after replication is enabled. So you would need to sync via cli to get any existing objects.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Yeah Rodrigo, I realized this while trying it out. Is there any way to sync/replicate data that was in the source bucket before creating the replication rule? I don't want my service to depend or use the AWS CLI.

Comment: The only way to do that initial sync is by CLI, or by using the api/sdk.

Comment: I've read that if you issue a copy request for each item in the bucket, with the source/destination the same, it will basically "touch" each object and that's enough to kick off a replication of the object to the other bucket. That of course relies on the CLI or SDK. There's no other way to do it, and honestly it seems a bit unreasonable to want to use AWS but want to avoid the CLI and SDK.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid to the use of CLI, Mark, is because I do not want a manual process to do the synchronisation for older files in the source. The Replication feature of S3 is exactly what I was looking, synchronizing objects automatically between source as destination whenever an object gets added to the source bucket.

Comment: If there is no other way to synchronise older data, one time synchronisation using CLI is not going to be an issue. Thanks Mark. Thanks Rodrigo.